# Getting error with Linq to Twitter - JsonData instance doesn't hold a string

Tags: asp.net, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I am now getting getting this error with on page that i embed a tweet - JsonData instance doesn't hold a string
Using Linq to twitter

```
var embeddedStatus =
               (from tweet in ctxTwitterContext.Status
                where tweet.Type == StatusType.Oembed &&
                    tweet.ID == TweetID
                select tweet.EmbeddedStatus)
               .SingleOrDefault();         


        string html = embeddedStatus.Html;
```

I have googled but not found his error with linq to twitter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter made an unannounced change of the cache_age property in the oembed response from a string to an int. I just updated LINQ to Twitter to fix this. You can see the changes and get the updated code here:

https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/36a7d5dac9235c67dd29917e6f8ccda69aed8baa